# Java EE 7 - Using @DELETE or @PUT with an entity body

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs

I have a service method which looks like this

```
public void deleteData(Data data) {
    this.dataDao.deleteData(data);
}
```

Data class have several fields in it. Somethig like this

```
private String name;
private String category;
private String discriminator;
private String description;
private String appName;

// getters & setters
```

I need to write a rest method for this. I was thinking to write something like this

```
@DELETE
@Path("/deleteData")
public Response deleteData(Data data) {
    // implementation
}
```

The problem is that using `@DELETE` with entity body is not recommended or widely used.

My question is if it's ok to use `@PUT` instead of `@DELETE`? I can't change the service method implementation so that's not an option. What's the next best alternative here?

**UPDATE**

In `dataDao.deleteData()` method, finding an object is not done by object's ID. It looks something like this:

```
DataEntity entity = this.findDataByNameAndAppName(data.getName(), data.getAppName());
```

I decided to do something like this:

```
@DELETE
@Path("/deleteDataset")
public Response deleteDataset(@QueryParam("name") String name,
                              @QueryParam("appName") String appName) {
// implementation...
}
```

I didn't find any example of `@DELETE` method with `@QueryParam`, though. All examples was using `@PathParam` instead.

Comment: *As you can see in the service implementation, I need it!* - OK you need it, but did you try another options? Like just receiving the id of the resource and pass it to the service wrapping into your `data` object? You do not need to keep your controllers with the same signature of your service, since you can receive any kind of info, wrap, handle, format, validate and then use it in the way you need it.

Comment: I would say that using `@DELETE` is the best options since it complies with the HTTP specification. You may just think better about your how can you integrate this layer with your legacy service. A good approach would be changing your URI to `/delete/{dataId}` and then handle it properly on your controller layer (instantiating a new `Data` object setting the id for example)

Comment: I usually use post method for these purposes.

Comment: I have seen many standard REST clients allowing users to have request body for DELETE operation. So i think it is perfectly ok to use request body for DELETE operation
check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request

Comment: @Amit Jersey mentioned in tags does not allow body for DELETE requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, [`DELETE`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5) is meant for... *deleting stuff*. So stick to that (without body).

You could either delete a resource using its unique identifier sent as a path parameter:

```
DELETE /resources/{id} HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
```

If you need to delete multiple resources, you could consider query parameters to filter a collection of resources and then delete the resources that match such criteria:

```
DELETE /resources?name=foo&category=bar HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
```

Comment: I wonder if using `@QueryParam` is an off pattern as much as providing an entity body?

Comment: @Yonetmen [URI](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986) is a resource identifier and nothing stops you from performing a `DELETE` request to a URI with a query string.